# override_settings in a Django view

Tags: python, django

One of my views depends on a `foo` function. The behaviour of this function is defined by a setting `BAR`. I have different views that make use of `foo`, and for one of them I would like `foo`to work as if it was slightly different. Unfortunately, `foo` is in a third-party dependency, so I cannot modify it.

I am considering doing as follows:

```
from django.test.utils import override_settings

def my_view(request):
    with override_settings(BAR="newvalue"):
        foo()
    ...
```

I know it's dirty and uncouth. But is it safe? Can I assume `settings.BAR` will have the right value in views other than `my_view`?

I am using Django 1.4 with Python 2.7, if that matters. My `foo` function is actually an upload function and I need it to upload files to different directories for different views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not something safe. Check the module you are trying to import: django.TEST.utils. It is something designed to be used on tests, not live.

If you override your settings, you will not only change it for your other views, but for your other users too. Settings are global and should be immutable.

I don't know what module you are working on, but you could try finding the class that you need to change in their code and subclass it and then extend it as needed or see if signals are of use to you. That way you are not invading the app functionality but can extend it as needed.

Comment: Could you expand on the reason why the change of settings will affect other views and users? Do you mean that concurrent processes will share the modified setting value?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#altering-settings-at-runtime And yeah, that is what i mean (read that somewhere while trying something simmilar).